# Syntax error in php code

Tags: php, mysql, variables, syntax

I'm a bit confused about the syntax of php.

I am trying to do a query without success and I'm stucked here for 2 days.

```
$query = ('UPDATE cegek SET CegNev='."$cegnev".', Kozpont='."$kozpont".', Bevetel='."$bevetel".', Alkalmazottak='."$alkalmazott".', Iparag='."$iparag".' WHERE id='."$id");
```

This returns `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$cegnev' (T_VARIABLE) in`

I tought that "" for variables and '' for string.

Anyone can help?

Comment: No syntax error in the code you've posted. Though the double quotes are not needed in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should use `concatenation operator ('.')` between two strings

Try this

```
$query = ("UPDATE cegek SET CegNev='".$cegnev."', Kozpont='".$kozpont."', Bevetel='".$bevetel."', Alkalmazottak='".$alkalmazott."', Iparag='".$iparag."' WHERE id=".$id."");
```

Comment: @sOnt glad to help you please accept as answer, if this worked for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this and start double quotes `"` your query :

```
$query = ("UPDATE cegek SET CegNev='".$cegnev."', Kozpont='".$kozpont."',
Bevetel='".$bevetel."', Alkalmazottak='".$alkalmazott."', Iparag='".$iparag."' 
WHERE id= '".$id."'");
```

Comment: I've already done it but since I'm a new user it says: lower than 15 reputation user's upvote doesn't show up to the publicity but it's recorded. :-/

Comment: i thinks fast of all submitted my corrected answer.

Comment: see my answer submitted time.